# Click Event is not working but mousedown does

Tags: jquery, html

i am facing one jquery issue. My Click Event is not working but mousedown does 
     this works

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.penEdit', function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('hOpen');
});
```

this doesn't works

```
$(document).on('click', '.penEdit', function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('hOpen');
});
```

I am loading html via ajax.

Any suggestions ..

Thanks

Comment: There's no logical reason that `click` wouldn't work but `mousedown` would. Do you have child elements inside `.penEdit` which have `stopPropagation()` or `return false` in their event handlers?

Comment: Both works http://jsfiddle.net/bf4ryax2/

Comment: Have a look at the error console. Are you getting any errors? The first thing you want do is make sure that the jQuery library is getting loaded. 

If it is, and there are no errors, then the next thing I'd be trying to confirm is which part is failing to fire? Is it the document ready handler? Or the onclick event? Or is that being fired but just not having the effect you want?

Answer (score 0):

For Me It works fine Check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hLtzL6tv/

```
$(document).on('click', '.penEdit', function () {
    $('.check').parent().addClass('hOpen');
});

$(document).on('mousedown', '.penEdit1', function () {
    $('.checkMouseDown').parent().addClass('hOpen');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to see if this works:

```
$( ".penEdit" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    console.log("I have clicked on penEdit :D");
});
```

If only there is an exception in a browser or as Rory has already said. Try in all browsers to see if you're not dealing with an exception.

Comment: It will work if he's going to add the functionality after the content has been loaded in the callback function, of course if he doesn't have any errors.

Comment: which is not a great idea

Answer (score -2):

There's no wrong with your code maybe your just confuse of the class you added.

try to add different class in the click event it should work.